# Aurelia Custom Element doesn't work inside Flex-Container

Tags: flexbox, aurelia, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

Hi we've recently started making custom elements in Aurelia. One of the rules we have established is that we cannot put class names on custom elements when using them.

This is causing problems for me because the custom element itself doesn't have any properties so it breaks a lot of styling.

In particular it breaks when put inside a flex-container.

I have read on [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom) that you can style the custom element using the `:host` selector, but I can't find any mention of this for Aurelia and I'm struggling to get it to work.

I have a codepen to demonstrate the problem [here](http://codepen.io/IOIIOOIO/pen/MpgyJa).

Answer (score 2):

You can style custom elements f.i. by referencing the element itself, like this:

```
o-custom-element {
    color: white;
    background: green;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

I've forked your codepen to show the change: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZeEdLL

Comment: Unfortunately another rule of ours we can't do that

Comment: Hmm, I always include this with the component (where `:host` would be, too, right?) and `require` the css in the component's view. IMO this is as good as `:host` itself, essentially it's just another name for it. But it's an interesting why `:host` won't work with Aurelia.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I didn't think of that. It might be that I was doing it wrong. If  I can't get `:host` to work then I'll try the `<require>` method. The thing is our whole team is new to custom elements so we're all learning as we go along. So we need to be careful to not let things get out of control every time Joe Soap has a new implementation idea.

Answer (score 1):

Put your custom element in the flex-item `div`:

```
<div class="half-container">
  <p>Breaking because of custom element (Flex container is yellow)</p>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item"></div>
    <div class="flex-item green">    
      <o-custom-element></o-custom-element>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to use `:host`, you'll have to put it in a `<style>` element inside the Shadow DOM of your custom element: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWYwxK

The problem is that you'll have to duplicate the rules and it's worse than adding classes to custom element...

Comment: I lean toward changing the rule but it's not my call. We work in a big team on a large project so they made that rule to try bring things under control. I just wish I could create a demo where the host is styled from inside the Shadow Dom with the :host selector. That would be a solution that would work for us.

Comment: @IOIIOOIO I've added an example with the use of :host.

Comment: Oh wow.. that easy... thanks million I'll work on somethonig like this. Should be an end to my headaches!